# The attachable property '%0' was not found in type '%1'

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, portable-class-library, xamlparseexception

I'm trying to load xaml using `XamlReader.Load(xamlstring)` in a PCL(for windows 8.1 & phone 8.1) project, but I'm always hitting the exception `"Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException"` at the below line:

```
string content = "<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>   
                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName='Tapped'>
                      <core:InvokeCommandAction Command=
                         '{Binding ElementName=ViewControlGrid,
                          Path=DataContext.ViewActionClickCommand}'
                        CommandParameter='{Binding RecordId}' />
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>";
```

And this is the namespace declaration

```
private static string namespaceString = 
       @"xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
        xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'
        xmlns:core='using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions' 
        xmlns:interactivity='using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity;assembly=Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions' ";
```

Any help to solve this issue? or What Im doing wrong?

EDIT:

The Exact Xaml string I'm trying to load is

```
    <DataTemplate xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions" xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity;assembly=Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <StackPanel Margin="0, 0, 0, 1" Background="#FFFFFFFF">
      <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
         <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=ViewControlGrid, Path=DataContext.ViewActionClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RecordId}" />
         </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
      </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ThisStackPanel}" Height="92.5">
         <Grid Width="55.5" Height="55.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18.5, 18.5, 0, 0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FFFFFFFF">
            <Button Margin="0" Content="{Binding DisplayValues[0]}" Foreground="#FF000000" Command="{Binding ElementName=ViewControlGrid, Path=DataContext.ViewActionClickCommand}" CommandParameter="Image" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNoStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
         </Grid>
         <Grid Width="259" Height="92.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="92.5, 0, 0, 0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FFFFFFFF">
            <Button Margin="0" Content="{Binding DisplayValues[1]}" Foreground="#FF000000" Command="{Binding ElementName=ViewControlGrid, Path=DataContext.ViewActionClickCommand}" CommandParameter="" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNoStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
         </Grid>
      </Grid>
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

EDIT 2:

This is the stacktrace of the excepton

```
The attachable property '%0' was not found in type '%1'. [Line: 3 Position: 379]
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlReader.Load(String xamlstring)
   at MyNamespace.MyProject.MyFolder.DataTemplates.TemplateConstructor.GetDataTemplateRow(List`1 zcRows, Boolean isPadding)}
```

EDIT 3:

The Exact Method:

```
 public static DataTemplate GetDataTemplateRow(List<ZCRow> zcRows , bool isPadding = false)
        {

            string rowsXaml = "<StackPanel Margin = '" + GetCardMargins(isPadding) 
                + "' Background='#FFFFFFFF' >";
            //template.

            rowsXaml += @"<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors><core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName='Tapped'><core:InvokeCommandAction Command='{Binding ElementName=ViewControlGrid, Path=DataContext.ViewActionClickCommand}' CommandParameter='{Binding RecordId}' /></core:EventTriggerBehavior></interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>";

            foreach(ZCRow row in zcRows)
            {
                rowsXaml += GetRowXaml(row);
            }
            rowsXaml += "</StackPanel>";

            string xaml = @"<DataTemplate " + namespaceString + "  >" + rowsXaml + "</DataTemplate>";
            Debug.WriteLine("Datatemplate is " + xaml);
            try
            {
                return (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What happens if you try to parse the line `string="<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors></interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>"`, for instance?

Comment: @Oliver same exception occurs.

Comment: Can you show the exact code you're using? The two snippets name variables `content` and `namespaceString` but your question mentions `xamlString`.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Updated my question.

Comment: @MohanRajNK - paste entire exception and stacktrace.

Comment: @O.O Updated my question.

Comment: You still haven't shown the complete code snippet that reproduces the problem. Please post that.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Added the Method that creates the data template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you were explicitly naming the assemblies in your XMLNS declaration. They were not the correct assembly references, so I just removed them:

```
xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' 
  xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' 
  xmlns:core='using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core' 
  xmlns:interactivity='using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity'
```

That works.

Comment: I tried the steps you mentioned above, but still the same exception occurs. I added the video here, reproducing the issue - http://1drv.ms/1F26430  
@PeterTorr-MSFT

Comment: Your ClassLibrary1 referenced the Behaviour assemblies, which was an error (got a yellow "!" icon in VS), and there was a compiler error :-). But I will update my answer to solve your problem.

Comment: I removed those assemblies naming in the declaration, but im still facing the same issue. This is the reference path I'm using  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\BehaviorsXamlSDKManaged\12.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\"  . I also tried this path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\BehaviorsXamlSDKManaged\12.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral" but none of them works!

Comment: I didn't add any assemblies to the PCL